# Single word for someone having a fetish for watching women breastfeed?

Tags: single-word-requests

My wife was wondering if there were people out there who have a thing for watching women breast feed their kids. I went to google it but nothing really came up (So I'm posting here to look for the right keyword), the only close Wikipedia article was for 'Erotic Lactation', which isn't really what I'm referring to.

Comment: A feeding frenzy?

Comment: I don't think such a word exists, but if we are talking about a sexual fetish for breast feeding, you could coin your own; a good guess would be _thelasmophilia_ or _thelasmatophilia_.

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be a single word?

Comment: I'd call the person a *voyeur* but the dictionary defines it as someone who derives sexual pleasure from watching two people  participating in sexual acts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetish for watching women breastfeed falls under Lactophilia.

Answer (score 2):

There might be some specialist lingo amongst the psychotherapist or FBI profiler set, but I don't think a word for this exists in the common tongue.

*Mammopticon*, perhaps?

Tethys was the Greek goddess of nursing (amongst other things) but I don't know Greek or Latin well enough to be erudite.

The word also needs to indicate whether the act of looking is a positive one, (as in one mother watching another mother nurse her child[ren],) or a negative act, (as in a leering, dirty old man peering in at a cracked window, with a frightened, yet defiant mother suckling her young, despite being ogled.)